# Why is autopairing for "<>" enabled in org-mode when I have electric-pair-mode enabled but do not have "<>" in electric-pair-pairs?

Tags: org-mode, parentheses, electric-pair-mode, autocompletion

Here's a snippet of my config related to electric-mode:

```
  (setq electric-pair-pairs '(
                  (?\{ . ?\})
                  (?\( . ?\))
                  (?\[ . ?\])
                  (?\" . ?\")
                  ))
  (electric-pair-mode t)
```

"<>" are only autopaired in org-mode when electric-mode is enabled and it doesn't happen in other major modes.

Comment: by Show-Paren minor mode? check it by `describe-mode`

Comment: @roomworoof , yes show-paren-mode is enabled. But isn't show-paren-mode only for highlighting matching parenthesis? (not creating or auto pairing)

Comment: I can't reproduce it in my `org-mode` with `electric-pair-mode` with your setting but you mean that it is complemented by ">". Do you have some kind of extension to your `org-mode`? It is recommended here to start with the minimum configuration by "emacs -Q" and then load them one by one to see how they behave.

Comment: @roomworoof , tried it with `emacs -Q` , "<" still gets complemented by ">" on enabling org-mode on scratch buffer. Even after setting electric-pair-pairs by evaluating the expression. Could it be a thing from different org-mode versions?

Comment: I am using Emacs 28.2 and the `org-version` is "Org mode version 9.5.5".

Comment: I have the same versions of Emacs and org-mode.